# Why does my samba shares becomes unnaccesible after a while using them?

Tags: windows, samba

I have a 12.04LTS server setup with samba so that I can access my share from windows machine. my problem is that I can sometimes connect to the share and after a short while the share is not accessible, I then try to connect again from a different windows machine, and I get the same problem. After a short while I am again able to access the share and it keep on giving me the same cycle. My samba configuration file is as follows:

```
[global]
    netbios name = PSSERVER
    server string =
    workgroup = PARADISE
    security = user
    encrypt passwords = yes
    smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
    interfaces = 192.168.0.1/8

[print$]
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = yes
    write list = root
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775

[printers]
    path = /tmp
    printable = yes
    guest ok = no
    browseable = no

[Pachsoft]
    comment = Pachsoft Pos System
    path = /Pachsoft
    writeable = yes
    create mode = 0600
    directory mode = 0700
```

I am able to ping the server on ip `192.168.0.100` as well as access it using webmin or putty or ssh secure shell which never drops me from the server so I know it is not a network issue but the samba share always drops intermittent. Could there be a problem with samba on ubuntu 12.04 lts? I have set it up as a headless.

the link to samba log http://paste.ubuntu.com/6075194/
there are only three folders in the samba cores directory ,nmbd nothing in,smbd with a file called core which shows ELF i don't know how to copy the contents, winbindd with nothin in

problem has been solved after i install virtual box which upgraded my server

Comment: Can you upload the content of the `/var/log/samba/log.smbd` and `/var/log/samba/cores` to paste.ubuntu.com, then edit your question and add the link?